# QtGui.QMessageBox.information and customizing it

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qmessagebox

According to you the doucmentation, `QtGui.QMessageBox.information()` function can be used to create a dialog box with many push buttons, using the following constants:

```
QMessageBox.Ok  An “OK” button defined with the AcceptRole .
QMessageBox.Open    A “Open” button defined with the AcceptRole .
QMessageBox.Save    A “Save” button defined with the AcceptRole .
QMessageBox.Cancel  A “Cancel” button defined with the RejectRole .
QMessageBox.Close   A “Close” button defined with the RejectRole .
QMessageBox.Discard     A “Discard” or “Don’t Save” button, depending on the platform, defined with the DestructiveRole .
QMessageBox.Apply   An “Apply” button defined with the ApplyRole .
QMessageBox.Reset   A “Reset” button defined with the ResetRole .
QMessageBox.RestoreDefaults     A “Restore Defaults” button defined with the ResetRole .
QMessageBox.Help    A “Help” button defined with the HelpRole .
QMessageBox.SaveAll     A “Save All” button defined with the AcceptRole .
QMessageBox.Yes     A “Yes” button defined with the YesRole .
QMessageBox.YesToAll    A “Yes to All” button defined with the YesRole .
QMessageBox.No  A “No” button defined with the NoRole .
QMessageBox.NoToAll     A “No to All” button defined with the NoRole .
QMessageBox.Abort   An “Abort” button defined with the RejectRole .
QMessageBox.Retry   A “Retry” button defined with the AcceptRole .
QMessageBox.Ignore  An “Ignore” button defined with the AcceptRole .
QMessageBox.NoButton    An invalid button.
```

It supports many features.

I've ben using the documentation for the [`QMessageBox`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMessageBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QMessageBox.setStandardButtons) class.

**My question is**, how do I change text of a push button in a message box?

Comment: You tagged the question `pyqt` but the documentation is for `PySide`... which of the two are you using? In fact `PyQt` documentation mentions the `setButtonText` method while `PySide` doesn't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`QMessageBox::setButtonText`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html#setButtonText) is what you need.

**Edit:**

Thanks to [Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679504/qtgui-qmessagebox-information-and-customizing-it/18679886#comment27517306_18679886) for pointing this out.

The `setButtonText` method mentioned above would work when used with PyQt/PySide library compiled against Qt4.3 or earlier. [Source](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside/source/d2a47ab8f27af7e74d34797464da85c128c17c37:PySide/QtGui/typesystem_gui_common.xml#L4317).

And for later versions, changing the text of a button would involve:

[`button = messageBox.button(which)`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMessageBox.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QMessageBox.button)

[`button.setText(text)`](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QAbstractButton.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QAbstractButton.setText)

Comment: Is this provided by `PySide` also? The documentation doesn't list this method(while `PyQt`'s documentation does).

Comment: @Bakuriu it is I guess but isn't documented, based on [this](http://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside/source/d2a47ab8f27af7e74d34797464da85c128c17c37:PySide/QtGui/typesystem_gui_common.xml#L4317). Answer updated. Nice catch.